# storing a password into an ms access database from a servlet page

Tags: servlets

I am getting username and password from the user in a registration form and saving the same in MS access database. When I do that, the password column in my database shows "null". So the login page does not work properly. What do I do?

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:db5");
Statement smt = con.createStatement();
String str = 
    "insert into table1(name1,sex,age,email,pwd,info) " 
    + "values('" + name + "','" + sex + "','" + age + "','" 
    + email + "','" + pwd + "','" + info + "')";
int val=smt.executeUpdate(str);
```

Comment: First and foremost thing is to replace that Statement with `PreparedStatement` to prevent SQL injection attack.

Comment: It's not clear how you are retrieving the password from servlet. Did you try printing it before persisting in the database to see if it is not null?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing passwords at all. You should store *hashes* of the passwords. This has ***very important legal consequences.*** Send the word 'non-repudation' up to your corporate lawyers.

Comment: yes thank you just now I checked, the value of pwd is null, I tried with manual values, it is showing the output, I'll check for mistakes in my code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:db5");
Statement smt = con.createStatement();
String str = 
    "insert into table1(name1,sex,age,email,pwd,info) " 
    + "values('" + name + "','" + sex + "','" + age + "','" 
    + email + "','" + pwd + "','" + info + "')";
smt.executeUpdate(str);
```